# with UNLIMITED time and strategy, what are the conditions for cat to catch the mouse?

Tags: calculus, physics

in a infinty 2D surface, with a cat and a mouse, the cat wants to catch the mouse.  MAX speed of cat and mouse are $V_{cat} , V_{mouse}$, max acceleration are $A_{cat} , A_{mouse}$. cat and mouse both know their last $\vec V_{cat}, \vec V_{mouse}$ and make the next move at same time. catching means move to the same point.

given $V_{cat} > V_{mouse}$ , with UNLIMITED time and strategy, what are the conditions for cat to catch the mouse?

is their any results or key word of this problem?

---

some thoughts:
**1.** if cat can catch the mouse, then :
$Time_0$ : cat and mouse at same point:$(X_0,Y_0)$, with any speed and direction:$\vec V_{cat}, \vec V_{mouse}$ , (such as $\vec V_{cat} = \vec V_{mouse}$)
$Time_1$ : cat should be capable of moving to any point:$(X_1,Y_1)$ that mouse can move to.
so there should be $A_{cat} >= A_{mouse}$ ? is this necessity? is this sufficiency?

**2.** with unlimited time cat can guess unlimit times where mouse will move to, so it is equal to mouse move first then cat move?

**3.** is this relative with their staring point?

Comment: All caps is the internet equivalent of yelling. If you want emphasis, use *italics* or **boldface**.

Comment: What a "move" is isn't defined.

Comment: "move": something like after every delta T they can use Ax change Vx, like the real world? non english speaker, not sure the correct expression.